# issue on recognize section on button action in tableview

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

I am working on iOS project which have one table with 2 sections.it also have search bar.In table cell I have a label and a button.in both section coming data from different array.Now problem is that I am not able to recognize cell of the section during tap on button.how i can recognize on that custom button action that which section of button is that? p;ease help me .I am pasting following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    else
    {
        UIView *subview;
        while ((subview= [[[cell contentView]subviews]lastObject])!=nil)
            [subview removeFromSuperview];

    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    UILabel *nameLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,12,230,40)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
    //lblCal.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];//[UIColor colorWithRed:190 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    nameLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    nameLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];//[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
    nameLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    nameLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
    btn.frame=CGRectMake(255,0,65, 65);
    btn.tag=indexPath.row;
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sendFollowUnfollowRequest:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    Team* team;
    if(isFiltered)
    {
        if (indexPath.section==0) {

            team = [filterFollow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_check@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        if(indexPath.section==1)
        {
            team = [filterUnFollow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_plus@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.section==0) {
            team = [followTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_check@2x"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        if(indexPath.section==1)
        {
            team = [unfollowTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_plus@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
    [nameLabel setText:team.teamName];
    return cell;
}

-(void)sendFollowUnfollowRequest:(UIButton *)tag
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: It seems that you want to add button on the section of tableview ?

Comment: No I want recognize section of table view after tap. if i do btn.tag=indexpath.section; it will work but then new problem will come for recognize array index which is indexpath,row.

Comment: Why dont you subclass uibutton and and add a indexpath property to it?

Comment: @amar: can you show me example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send row and section information seperately so make tag as

```
Tag= row*1000+section.
```

now from tag get section and row value using `row= tag/1000` `section =tag%1000`

use this value to make correct index path or find some better then 2 mins solution to get that.

Caution its a workaround correct will be to
 Subclass UIButton
    Add a indexpath property int it
    make your class to make button object and insted of tag set indexpath property.

in CustomButton.h

```
@interface CustomButton :UIButton
@property (nonatomic,assign)NSIndexPath *path;
@end
```

in CustomButton.m

```
@implementation CustomButton
@synthesize path;
@end
```

Use this custom button on your table view cell and instead of tag set path property

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the `UITableViewCell` using button, and then get its `indexPath` to identify the section. Like this:

> UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[tag superview]
>   superview];
>
> int section = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell].section;

Where `tag` is your button that is being tapped. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 NSString *tempTag=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
 btn.tag=[tempTag intValue];
```

Comment: for section 0 button tag value is 00,01,02,03, for section 1 button tag value is 10 , 11, 12 , 13 ,14

Answer (score 0):

I think , it might be a simple mistake you haven't seen. I have seen this.

```
btn.tag=indexPath.row;
```

But you have talked about section.
so you can try this..

```
btn.tag=indexPath.section;
```

In your method,

```
-(void)sendFollowUnfollowRequest:(UIButton *)button
{
   if (button.tag == 0)
    self.searchBarDataSource = //first Section Search Bar;
   else if (button.tag == 1)
    self.searchBarDataSource = //Second Section Search Bar;

   /* show search Bar */
}
```